# animated gradient (javascript) background will not extend to full height of window

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, linear-gradients

I have an animated gradient as a background div on my website. However, whenever I try to apply css styling to the HEIGHT such as "100%" or "background: cover", etc., so that it will reach the bottom of any window, the gradient just stops functioning. It only seems to like being styled with a discreet pixel height, which is not ideal. Below is my css and html. Any ideas on how to get the gradient to scale to fit windows as opposed to being just a single discreet length? I have it set at width:100% which functions perfectly in that direction so I am stumped! Link:
http://studiopowell.net/TEST_gradient.html

```
#gradient

{
  width: 100%;
  height: 1200px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0.1;
  margin-top: -850px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;

}

</head>
<body>
<div class="titles"><img src="archive-icon.png" width="185" height="185" alt="studio powell michael powell studiopowell art artist books installation video" /><br /><br />M I C H A E L &nbsp; P O W E L L<br /><br /></div>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></a>
<div id="gradient"> 
</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like works here, maybe you have a problem with your browser?

Comment: Use `height: 100%; position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;`, and remove the `margin-top`. Is that solving it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can solve your problem by locating the gradient div *above* the rest of the document, and using `position:absolute` as @blex mentioned in his comment:

http://jsfiddle.net/qj1nz13p/

### HTML

```
<div id="gradient">
</div>
<div class="titles">
    <img src="archive-icon.png" width="185" height="185" alt="studio powell michael powell studiopowell art artist books installation video" /><br/><br/>
    M I C H A E L &nbsp; P O W E L L<br/><br/>
</div>
<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="archive-icon.png"><img src="ruby ball.jpg" alt="" width="200" /></a>
```

### CSS

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#gradient {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    opacity: 0.1;
    position:absolute;
    z-index: -99999;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
var colors = new Array(
[62,35,255],
[60,255,60],
[255,35,98],
[45,175,230],
[255,0,255],
[255,128,0]);
var step = 0;
//color table indices for:
// current color left
// next color left
// current color right
// next color right
var colorIndices = [0,1,2,3];
//transition speed
var gradientSpeed = 0.0004;
function updateGradient()
{
if ( $===undefined ) return;
var c0_0 = colors[colorIndices[0]];
var c0_1 = colors[colorIndices[1]];
var c1_0 = colors[colorIndices[2]];
var c1_1 = colors[colorIndices[3]];
var istep = 1 - step;
var r1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[0] + step * c0_1[0]);
var g1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[1] + step * c0_1[1]);
var b1 = Math.round(istep * c0_0[2] + step * c0_1[2]);
var color1 = "rgb("+r1+","+g1+","+b1+")";
var r2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[0] + step * c1_1[0]);
var g2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[1] + step * c1_1[1]);
var b2 = Math.round(istep * c1_0[2] + step * c1_1[2]);
var color2 = "rgb("+r2+","+g2+","+b2+")";
$('#gradient').css({
background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from("+color1+"), to("+color2+"))"}).css({
background: "-moz-linear-gradient(left, "+color1+" 0%, "+color2+" 100%)"});
step += gradientSpeed;
if ( step >= 1 )
{
step %= 1;
colorIndices[0] = colorIndices[1];
colorIndices[2] = colorIndices[3];
//pick two new target color indices
//do not pick the same as the current one
colorIndices[1] = ( colorIndices[1] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
colorIndices[3] = ( colorIndices[3] + Math.floor( 1 + Math.random() * (colors.length - 1))) % colors.length;
}
}
setInterval(updateGradient,10);// JavaScript Document
```

Also, I changed `z-index` from 10 to -99999; the gradient background should be *underneath* everything, right? Not sure why you had 10...

Comment: Thank you!! *face palm* very intuitive and helpful answers. Learning a ton. :) And thanks @blex as well.

Answer (score 0):

Apply styling to your HTML tag: http://jsfiddle.net/n6xnsv34/

```
html{
  height:100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(red, blue); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue); /* Standard syntax */

}
```